# Run jar failed with Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.tsu.orchestration.WeeklyTSUOrchestrator

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I build my assembly with scala build.sbt: TSUOrchestrationLogic-assembly.jar

In my META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, the Main-Class header is right:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: TSUOrchestrationLogic
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title: TSUOrchestrationLogic
Specification-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mycompany.tsu.orchestration.WeeklyTSUOrchestrator
```

When I ran it with: java -jar ./TSUOrchestrationLogic-assembly.jar

It failed with error:

```
Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.tsu.orchestration.WeeklyTSUOrchestrator
```

But if I unzip it to a folder with: jar xf TSUOrchestrationLogic-assembly.jar, ran it with class directly, it works:

```
java com.mycompany.tsu.orchestration.WeeklyTSUOrchestrator
```

What might be the root cause of my jar assembly, how can I diagnose the root causes?

Comment: Tried to run the class explicitly, failed with the same error: java -cp ./TSUOrchestrationLogic-assembly.jar com.mycompany.tsu.orchestration.WeeklyTSUOrchestrator

Comment: Sounds as if folder `com` might not be at the root of the jar

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean com isn't at the root of jar? After I use jar xf TSUOrchestrationLogic-assembly.jar, com folder isn't at the root. How can I tell? What's more, if I want to set com to the root of jar, how can I do it?

Comment: I tried with jar tf. I can see the folder: com/mycompany/tsu/orchestration/ and
com/mycompany/tsu/orchestration/WeeklyTSUOrchestrator.class

Comment: *I tried with jar tf. I can see the folder: com/mycompany...* In that case it *is* at the root. I can't explain why you're having a problem

Comment: Make sure your main class begins with declaration `package com.mycompany.tsu.orchestration;`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have double checked that. The code used to work, but after we merged to new dependencies, it stopped working. As Java has so many dependencies, they all mingled together. We tried several strategies trying to find the root cause, not ver successful.